# Can I Read Tables in SQL Server From MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server

I'm doing a page in PHP using MySQL, but I need some data from a SQL Server 2008. Is possible with query's, read the data in SQL Server 2008 from MySQL server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, not from the MySQL server but it may be possible to access the MSSQL DB via a separate ODBC connection.

Comment: Oh, so I need to make another connection? I have to have one mssql_connect and one mysql_connect?

Comment: Yep, thats what will need to happen.